# Did NATO bombs cause significant damage to Libya's water systems in 2011?

Tags: military, war, libya

NATO intervened against [Muammar Gaddafi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muammar_Gaddafi) in the [2011 military invention in Libya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_military_intervention_in_Libya).

The [Great Man-Made River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Man-Made_River) is a major irrigation project to supply fresh water across Libya.

Human Rights Investigations claimed in 2011 that [NATO bombed the pipe-making plant](https://humanrightsinvestigations.org/2011/07/27/great-man-made-river-nato-bombs/) required to maintain the water supply:

> NATO has admitted that its jets attacked the pipe factory on 22 July, claiming in justification that it was used as a military storage facility and rockets were launched from there.

A [2011 YouTube video](https://youtu.be/Km-G80Skj-0) purports to show a fountain of water from a NATO-bombed part of the Great Man-Made River.

> One of the first things NATO bombed was the Great Man Made River.

Did the Libyan Man-Made River fail due to strategic bombing by NATO?